# How to make form for uploading dozens of photos and rename them with certain names with php (flat file)

Tags: php, html, image, upload, rename

I'm trying to make simple code for uploading images with specific names for my webstore catalog. My catalog has 50 different products and all of them has that one img to be viewed by customers.

What I want to do, is uploading form for 50 different product images. Form should have input="file" for each product and when one/some/all of them is changed and submited, those images should process into specific names (product_1, product_2, product_3) and overwrite existing file if there is one. Off course, I would like all images to come out in specific format and size.

All I know about php, javascript and jquery - is what I find with google and mostly use those ready codes as they are in my projects, so please be patient with me, learning every day so much new!

Here's example from my html:

```
<form id="admin" action="<?php echo $_server['php-self'];  ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="uniForm">

<button name="submit" id="submit_button_id" type="submit" class="submitButton">Submit</button>

<input name="new_image01" id="new_image01" type="file" class="fileUpload" />  
<input name="new_image02" id="new_image02" type="file" class="fileUpload" />  
<input name="new_image03" id="new_image03" type="file" class="fileUpload" />  

</form
```

And my childish really long code:

```
<?php

$newfilename = "cart_img01.jpg";
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          if (isset ($_FILES['new_image01'])){
              $imagename = $newfilename;
              $source = $_FILES['new_image01']['tmp_name'];
              $target = "cart-img/".$imagename;
              move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

              $imagepath = $imagename;
              $save = "cart-img/" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
              $file = "cart-img/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

              list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 

              $modwidth = 600; 

              $diff = $width / $modwidth;

              $modheight = $height / $diff; 
              $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
              imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

              imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ; 

              $save = "cart-img/sml_" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
              $file = "cart-img/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

              list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 

              $modwidth = 350; 

              $diff = $width / $modwidth;

              $modheight = $height / $diff; 
              $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
              imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

              imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ;

          }
        }  

?>
```

..and this goes that 49 times more.

Comment: You can loop through it... `for ($i = 1; $i < $numberOfUploads; $i++){ $file = $_FILES[sprintf('new_upload%02d', $i)]; /* use $file hereafter */ }`

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should be using arrays for your inputs. If you really want to code out say 12 file uploads you would do

```
<input name="new_images[]" type="file" class="fileUpload" />
```

If you are applying something special using jQuery you can refer to the class instead of the id

```
$(".fileUpload").whateverYouNeedHere();
```

Next in your code, when the user submits you will have an array of "new_images" and you can go through them using a foreach. So something like this (sorry if there are errors)

```
<?php

$save_directory = 'cart-img/';

foreach($_FILES['new_images'] as $key => $input_image)
{
  if($input_image['error'] == 0)
  {
    // 2nd parameter just makes your filename "cart-img/cart_img0.jpg"
    $filename  = $save_directory . 'cart_img' . $key .'.jpg';
    $thumbnail = $save_directory . 'sml_cart_img' . $key .'.jpg'
    saveFile($input_image['tmp_name'], $filename, $thumbnail); // Key is 0 through whatver, not very good as things will be over-ridden
  }
}

function saveFile($tmp_name, $file_name, $thumbnail_file_name)
{
  // Save File
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file_name);

  // Resize original to 600
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_name);
  $modwidth = 600; 
  $diff = $width / $modwidth;
  $modheight = $height / $diff; 

  $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight);
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name);
  imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height);
  imagejpeg($tn, $file_name, 100); // Just overwrite the original in our case, you could have a new name here, but in your code you didn't

  // Create Thumbnail
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_name);
  $modwidth = 300; 
  $diff = $width / $modwidth;
  $modheight = $height / $diff; 

  $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight);
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name);
  imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height);
  imagejpeg($tn, $thumbnail_file_name, 100);
}
```